# Calculate two limits related to a recursively defined sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, recursion

I am currently studying mathematical analysis, specifically the theory of sequences, and I have come across a challenging problem in my homework that I am unable to solve. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or insight you can provide.

The problem is as follows:

> Consider the sequence defined recursively by $x_{n+2}=x_{n+1}+\frac{x_n}{\ln x_n}$ for $n\geq 0$, where $x_0,x_1>1$. I am tasked with finding the limits of two expressions.
> Firstly, I need to determine $$c:=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\ln^2 x_n}{n}.$$
> Secondly, I need to calculate $$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\ln^2x_n-cn}{\sqrt{n}}.$$

Comment: Does $\ln^2 x_n$ mean $\ln(\ln(x_n))$?

Comment: I think, it's $(\ln x_n)^2$.

Comment: Is it possible for you to simulate this sequence online (maybe obtain your code using ChatGPT), and at least hazard a guess at the answer? Thanks.

Comment: If $c$ exists, then the second limit is 0, no?

Comment: @DS Why so? $\lim\varepsilon_n=0\not\Rightarrow\lim\varepsilon_n\sqrt n=0$.

Comment: @LipingLi This is an interesting problem but you say nothing about your attempts at solving it. You just state your homework and ask for assistance... this is not the way on this site. I am very surprised no one pointed this out and the question was even upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

You have by an easy induction that $x_n>1$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$, then $(x_n)$ is increasing and it's going to infinity otherwise its limit $l$ would be such that $l=l+\frac{l}{\ln(l)}$ hence $l=0$ : contradiction.

Now you can use that to get $x_{n+2}\sim x_{n+1}$ and from $\displaystyle \frac{x_{n+2}}{x_{n+1}}=1+\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}\ln(x_n)}$ you also have $\ln(x_{n+2})-\ln(x_{n+1})\sim \frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}\ln(x_n)}\sim\frac{1}{\ln(x_n)}$ and $\ln(x_{n+2})+\ln(x_{n+1})\sim 2\ln(x_{n+1})$ hence $\ln^2(x_{n+2})-\ln^2(x_{n+1})\sim 2$. Then $\ln^2(x_n)\sim 2n$ and hence $c=2$. For the other limit try to use first order expansions instead of equivalences as I did.

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks a lot.